# How to solve this for every integer n, ⌊⌊n/2⌋/3⌋=⌊n/6⌋?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions, computational-mathematics

The hint that is given for this question is
Start by dividing the proof into two cases: n is
even and n is odd. In case n is odd, use the quotientremainder theorem with divisor equal to 6 to divide into
three cases: n 5 6k11, n 5 6k13, and n 5 6k15 for
some integer k. You will need to consider a total of four
cases.

Comment: If everything else fails, consider all six cases: $n=6k+l$ with $l=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Comment: Can you kindly explain it further?

Comment: I am afraid I can't because I am not sure what you already know about this problem. For example, from your reply it is not clear whether you already know that you can divide $n$ by $6$ and you get a remainder between $0$ and $5$, which then implies that $n=6k+l$ ($k$=quotient, $l$=remainder).

Comment: This is why we on MSE insist that the questions always provide some background not only about the problem, but also about the knowledge that the poster has about the problem, so that the answers can be written at the appropriate level. Please feel free to update your question. Refer to [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the four cases (specifically, one of the three cases where $n$ is odd):

Suppose $n = 6k + 5$, where $k$ is an integer. Then the LHS evaluates to
\begin{align*}
\left\lfloor \frac{ \lfloor n/2 \rfloor }{3} \right\rfloor &= \left\lfloor \frac{ \lfloor (6k+5)/2 \rfloor }{3} \right\rfloor
= \left\lfloor \frac{ \lfloor 3k + 5/2 \rfloor }{3} \right\rfloor
\\
&= \left\lfloor \frac{ \lfloor (3k + 2) + 1/2 \rfloor }{3} \right\rfloor \left\lfloor \frac{ 3k + 2 }{3} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor k + \frac{2}{3} \right\rfloor = k
\end{align*}
while the RHS is
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n}{6} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{6k+5}{6} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor k + \frac{5}{6} \right\rfloor = k.$$
So both sides are equal. Now it just remains to check this for all other cases, which are fairly similar.

Comment: As per [Meta article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards): "*If you encounter a low-quality question, don't answer it immediately. Instead, direct the user to the meta post [How to Ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Help them to understand what the standards are on this site, and consider offering advice on how they might improve their question. Make it clear that there are expectations for participation in this community, but always remain polite.*"